# Extracting factor from quadrinomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

As I'v learned about polynomials, I run into this quadrinomial:

$$x^3+300x^2+30000x-953125 = 0$$

I've been studied how to factor this quadrinomial but didn't quite understand how it's done, here is how I've studied(I probably didn't get the following steps wrong):

I should ask myself how big `x` has to be for the linear term and the constant to add to `0`.

Divide the constant by the coefficient of the linear term, its around `30`, now how would I know if `30` is a reasonable approximation for `x`?

I should check the result when `x = 30` for the quadratic and cubic terms and if each of them is smaller than the constant then it's a reasonable approximation.

As I checked with other polynomials dividing the constant with the linear term always produce a number that is pretty close to the `x`.

I know I'm probably misunderstood most of the things, but if anyone can help me figure out why and how I will be very thankful.

**Edit:**

I'm sorry for not being clear about my question, **I** try to understand why after dividing the constant by the linear and getting something around `30`, why It's considered as reasonable approximation for the factor when both of the following came up true: $$30^3 < 30*30,000$$ and $$300*30^2 < 30*30,000$$ It's something I've learned and couldn't understand why it's true to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the fact that if your polinomial 
$$
f = x^3+300 x^2+30000 x-953125
$$
has an integer root $\alpha$ (so that $x - \alpha$ is a divisor of $f$), then $\alpha$ divides the constant term $953125 = 5^{6} \cdot 61$. (Also, a rational root of $f$ has to be an integer, as $f$ is monic.)

Try the divisors of $5^{6} \cdot 61$, starting with the small positive ones, and you will soon find a root$\dots$

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Since you are looking for a zero which is **a divisor of $953125 =5^{6} \cdot 61$ and which is near $30$**, then you may supect it to be equal to $\color{red}{25}$, this may lead you to write
$$
\begin{align}
& x^3+300x^2+30000x-953125\\\\
=\:&\left(x^3+3\color{red}{25}x^2+3\color{red}{8125}x\right)-\left(\color{red}{25}x^2+\color{red}{8125}x+953125\right)\\\\
=\:&\color{red}{x}\left(x^2+325x+38125\right)-\color{red}{25}\times\left(x^2+325x+38125\right)\\\\
=\:&(\color{red}{x-25})\left(x^2+325x+38125\right).
\end{align}
$$