# Monic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Recently I've learned that when a given polynomial is a monic polynomial, then this polynomial root has to be a rational root.

As far as I know, to figure out if a given polynomial is a monic polynomial I need to make sure that this polynomial is a univariate polynomial and that the leading coefficient of highest degree is equal to 1.

**What I can't understand** is what makes monic polynomial so special so that the root is rational?

**Edit:**

For better explanation about what I couldn't understand, please check out this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179320/extracting-factor-from-quadrinomial) that I've asked, from the answer, and I quote:

> Also, a rational root of $f$ has to be an integer, as $f$ is monic

Comment: Well, if you think of $x^2+1$  its monic but only has complex roots

Comment: What you might have heard is that if a monic polynomial with integer coefficients has a rational root then that root is an integer. That is one useful theorem that sounds like what you are saying.

Comment: … which is called [Gauss’s lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)) (like a lot of other lemmata), by the way.

Comment: I edited my question for better explanation.